# ImportError: No module named pyfftw

Tags: python, fftw, pyfftw

Im using Ubuntu 13.10 with python 2.7.  When running code i get this error.  I installed FFTW and not sure why I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
import math

from gnuradio import gr

import numpy
import scipy.signal
import pyfftw
```

this is where I get the error.  Any help would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Did you also install [pyfftw](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW)? If so, how?

Comment: Do you have more than one python instance? If you install a tool from the commandline tool such as pip, or easy_install it will reference the python instance it can see from the shell. If there are multiple, that could be a different one from the one you are using above. That said, @darthbith 's comment is probably correct. Just because you installed something doesn't mean you have the python bindings for it.

Comment: I used pip install pyfftw.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sys.path in python. That tells you the module search path. If it is not in there, and not in the %PYTHONPATH% path (which should be in sys.path also) then it should not be able to find it. If you install a module, the interpreter still needs to know where to look for it, if it's not in the default search location.